# Semi-colon required, optional, or disallowed in gRPC option value?

Tags: grpc, proto3

I'm seeing one piece of code like the following:

`rpc SayFallback (FooRequest) returns (FooResponse) {
        option (com.example.proto.options.bar) = {
            value : "{ message:\"baz\" }";
        };
    }`

and another like the following:

`rpc SayFallback (FooRequest) returns (FooResponse) {
        option (com.example.proto.options.bar) = {
            value : "{ message:\"baz\" }"
        };
    }`

The first has a `;` on the line with `value` while the second doesn't. Are either OK according to the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are considered optional.  See the [protobuf file source](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/v3.2.0/src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc#L1934) snippet:

```
  while (!TryConsumeEndOfDeclaration("}", NULL)) {
    if (AtEnd()) {
      AddError("Reached end of input in method options (missing '}').");
      return false;
    }

    if (TryConsumeEndOfDeclaration(";", NULL)) {
      // empty statement; ignore
    } else {
      ...
  }
```